# Why am I getting a nonzero voltage out of this inverting amplifier op-amp when I ground the input?

Tags: operational-amplifier, loop-gain

The circuit in my figure is an inverting amplifier with a gain of -100.

[image]

My instructor asked me to ground the inputs to see what would happen and discuss what should happen for an ideal op-amp. In an ideal op-amp, I think there would be no problem, because the inputs should have equal voltage anyway. So the output would be 0V.

[image]

In a non-ideal op-amp, I know that there exists an offset voltage. By grounding the input, I somehow cause the output to saturate to 14 V DC. But I don't understand the mechanism behind this saturation.

I did some reading and found that when an op-amp is operating in open loop mode, then if both inputs are grounded, the input offset voltage will be multiplied by the full open loop gain.

Based on the comments I've received, I can understand how grounding R2 effectively nullifies my feedback, because the "-" input on the op-amp doesn't feel the feedback. Thus I'm effectively operating in open loop mode, and the input offset voltage is multiplied by the open loop gain.

Comment: Try grounding the input to the circuit.

Comment: You are, in effect, working in open loop mode as the output has no way of feeding back to either input.

Comment: "However, I'm not operating in open loop mode here."  Are you sure? Did you ground both + and - inputs right on the IC?

Comment: Your schematic is a mess. Please draw a schematic that represents your actual test situation with a decent degree of clarity.

Comment: I second Andy aka. You'll be confusing yourself by such a convoluted and squished schematic. Put the op-amp horizontally, put some space between the op-amp and the virtual instruments (meters and power sources).

Comment: @Andyaka Cleaned up the schematic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've grounded both inputs to the 741, which means it *is* operating open-loop. It's a simulation so there's not even any resistance (not that it would matter that much with the resistor values shown).

[image]

So you're getting the offset voltage multiplied by the open-loop gain (the negative of that, in fact, the way we usually define it).

If you short the other end of the 1kΩ resistor to ground you'll get -100 times the offset voltage at the output (which should not cause the amplifier to rail).

If you short the feedback resistor (but not the 1kΩ resistor) you'll the negative of the offset voltage at the output.

An "ideal" op-amp with inputs shorted has an indeterminate output. The gain is infinite and the offset voltage is zero, and \$0 \cdot \infty\$  is indeterminate.

Comment: If my question is re-opened, I did update my figures. So you may want to update the figure in your answer. I wonder if you could also comment on what would happen for an ideal op-amp with both inputs grounded.

Answer (score 1):

In the real world the voltages are never equal because of differences in matching of components. The inputs are made from transistors (FETs BJTs) and built in silicon on IC's. Because these are not perfectly matched, the input bias current can be different, the voltage offset can be different. If an opamp has no feedback it will usually go to one of the rails and turn into something like a comparator where it's either off or on.